# Can't see .git folder in win 10

Tags: windows, git

I cloned an empty project to win 10 folder but can't see anything, even with hidden files turned on

Cloning into 'work'...
info: please complete authentication in your browser...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
PS C:\Users\me\vscode_projects> ls
PS C:\Users\me\vscode_projects> git clone https://github.com/repo/work
fatal: destination path 'work' already exists and is not an empty directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can always do a dir/a to see the hidden files from the command line:

```
c:\Temp\test>dir /a
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is E8EE-21DF

 Directory of c:\Temp\test

2023-04-07  13:11    <DIR>          .
2023-04-07  13:11    <DIR>          ..
2023-04-07  13:11    <DIR>          .git
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  197 014 888 448 bytes free
```

You can run

```
c:\>dir .git /s /a
```

To locate all git folders on your hard drive.

Also, do make sure there is an existing folder with the same name as the repo that you try to clone.